# 時系列の横結合(merge)の質問について

Tags: python, pandas

2つCSVファイルがあります：area1.csv area2.csv
時間列の項目名はないので、
時間を基準に横結合したいなら、どうやって修正したら良いでしょうか？
ご教示いただけましたら幸いですので、どうぞよろしくお願いします！
df1 = pd.read_csv(area1.csv,index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(area2.csv,index_col=0)
df3 = pd.merge([df1, df2], how="outer")
df3.to_csv(area3.csv, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

**余談**

削除されてしまった「[シェルスクリプト(bash)で複数ファイルの結合](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93879)」ですが、シェルスクリプトでは `join` コマンドを使います。

```bash
$ join -t, -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -o auto -e '' area1.csv area2.csv > area3.csv
```